# Accessing an object outside of a nested function in Python

Tags: python, variables, object, global-variables

I'm trying to make a program that is effectively an alarm clock. It's more complicated than it might seem that it needs to be, but there are reasons for that, that I won't go into here. The issue I'm having, though, is that I create an Alarm object inside a nested function, but whatever I do, I can't get that object to be accessed outside of that function... I've attached the abridged code below. Any of the calls to "check" or "set" etc. outside of setAlarm can never find the "alarm" variable. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong — I tried declaring the variable as global, as you'll see, but it still doesn't work out...

Thanks!

```
class Alarm(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, datetime, grace, close):
        super(Alarm, self).__init__()
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.grace = grace
        self.close = close
        self.keep_running = True

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.keep_running:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                if now > self.datetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=self.grace):
                    print "Oh no! It's %02d:%02d, which is %d minutes past your alarm time of %02d:%02d!" % (now.hour,now.minute,self.grace,self.datetime.hour,self.datetime.minute)
                    print "ALARM NOW!\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a"
                    break
            time.sleep(10)
        except:
            return
    def just_die(self):
        self.keep_running = False

def setAlarm():
    print "What time would you like to set the alarm for? (in 00:00 military time please)"
    wakeup = raw_input()
    wakeuphour = int(wakeup[:2])
    wakeupmin = int(wakeup[3:])
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour > wakeuphour or (now.hour == wakeuphour and now.minute > wakeupmin):
        alarmday = now + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        alarmtime = datetime.datetime(alarmday.year,alarmday.month,alarmday.day,wakeuphour,wakeupmin)
    else:
        alarmtime = datetime.datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,wakeuphour,wakeupmin)
    close = 15
    grace = 5
    alarm = Alarm(alarmtime, grace, close)
    if alarmtime.day != now.day:
        print "Your alarm is set for %02d:%02d tomorrow." % (alarmtime.hour,alarmtime.minute)
    else:
        print "Your alarm is set for %02d:%02d today." % (alarmtime.hour, alarmtime.minute)

def runAlarm():
    setAlarm()
    alarm.start()
    while True:
        print "You can say 'stop', 'check', 'change', 'set', or 'quit'"
        text = str(raw_input())
        if text == "stop":
            if alarm != 0:
                alarm.just_die()
                alarm = 0
                print "Okay, I've cancelled the alarm."
            else:
                print "There was no alarm to stop..."
        elif text == "check":
            if alarm == 0:
                print "Sorry, you don't have any alarm set. To create an alarm, type 'set'"
            else:
                pass
        elif text == "change":
            pass
        elif text == "set":
            alarm = 0
            setAlarm()
            alarm.start()
        elif text == "quit":
            print "Sure thing. Bye bye!"
            break
        else:
            print "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again."
```

Comment: What nested function are you asking about? I don't see any nested functions here at all.

Comment: Also, you've got some other errors in there. For example, `alarm` is an `Alarm` object. How can it be `== 0`? Unless you define a `__eq__` method for your `Alarm` objects, that will always be false. Also, why are you calling `str(raw_input())`? The `raw_input` function always returns a string. Are you trying to accomplish something, like getting a printable string representation out of it? If so, you're not; that `str` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created `alarm` as a local variable. Variables defined in a function are local by default, and local means exactly what it sounds like—it only exists inside that function.

You *could* fix this by explicitly making it a global variable. That's not a great idea, but it's the smallest change. Just add the statement `global alarm` to the top of both `setAlarm` and every function that wants to access it.

A better solution is to `return alarm` from `setAlarm`. Then, in the code that calls it, just store the return value. For example:

```
def setAlarm():
    # your existing code
    return alarm

def runAlarm():
    alarm = setAlarm()
    # your existing code
```

Now, `runAlarm` has its own local reference to the same object, also named `alarm`, so it can use that.

Comment: Perfect, this makes sense (both fixes). I've never been super clear on the use of "global"; I didn't know I had to put it in both functions, but that makes sense. And the second thing you mentioned seems easier. Thanks so much!!